# add MAX to existing criteria in LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I have the folowing query that pulls an item from a list.

```
latestDoc = openDocs.Where(d => d.docBatchId == HARD_CODED_ID).FirstOrDefault();
```

I want to also find the row with the latestStatusDate...I'm using the MAX function but  it returns null, as I believe Max is looking for the max of **all** the docs, I simply want it to find the max of the docs that contain this batchId

```
latestDoc = openDocs.Where(d => d.docBatchId == HARD_CODED_ID && d.prodStatus == openDocs.Max(d => d.ProdStatus)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Any ideas?

Ta, 
yogi

Comment: take the `First` from `OrderByDescending`

Comment: Try ordering your results using `OrderBy` descending, then your first result will be the maximum date.

Comment: Thanks to all, I submitted first answer as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `OrderByDescending`:

```
latestDoc = openDocs.Where(d => d.docBatchId == HARD_CODED_ID)
    .OrderByDescending(d => d.StatusDate)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like this will get you what you are looking for

```
var latestDoc = openDocs.Where(d => d.docBatchId == HARD_CODED_ID)
    .OrderByDescending(d => d.ProdStatus)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

The following c# compiles and runs in [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/)...

```
    var openDocs = new [] {
    new { 
        docBatchId = 123,
        StatusDate = new DateTime(2014, 01, 01)
    },
    new {
        docBatchId = 123,
        StatusDate = new DateTime(2014, 01, 02)
    },
    new {
        docBatchId = 123,
        StatusDate = new DateTime(2014, 01, 03)
    }
    ,
    new {
        docBatchId = 456,
        StatusDate = new DateTime(2014, 01, 04)
    }
};

var HARD_CODED_ID = 123;

var latestDoc = (from doc in openDocs 
                where doc.docBatchId == HARD_CODED_ID
                select doc.StatusDate).Max();

latestDoc.Dump();
```

The result is 03/01/2014 00:00:00 (3rd January 2014), which is the latest statusDate for the 3 items with a docBatchId of 123.